# I'm receiving error "Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received."

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I've created a CRUD app using RTK query with typescript, I've built it by watching a youtube tutorial and everything works fine, but I'm getting three errors in the console: `Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.` But it doesn't crash the app.
Here is my Repo `https://github.com/Adrian333Dev/rtk-query-typescript`

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

[image]

```
PostService.ts :
```

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/react";
import { IPost } from "../models/IPost";

export const postAPI = createApi({
  reducerPath: "postAPI",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:5000",
  }),
  tagTypes: ["Post"],
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    fetchAllPosts: build.query<IPost[], number>({
      query: (limit: number = 5) => ({
        url: "/posts",
        params: {
          _limit: limit,
        },
      }),
      providesTags: (result) => ["Post"],
    }),
    createPost: build.mutation<IPost, IPost>({
      query: (post) => ({
        url: "/posts",
        method: "POST",
        body: post,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ["Post"],
    }),
    uptadePost: build.mutation<IPost, IPost>({
      query: (post) => ({
        url: `/posts/${post.id}`,
        method: "PUT",
        body: post,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ["Post"],
    }),
    deletePost: build.mutation<IPost, IPost>({
      query: (post) => ({
        url: `/posts/${post.id}`,
        method: "DELETE",
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ["Post"],
    }),
  }),
});
```

```
store.ts :
```

```js
import { postAPI } from "./../services/PostService";
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  [postAPI.reducerPath]: postAPI.reducer,
});

export const setupStore = () => {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
      getDefaultMiddleware().concat(postAPI.middleware),
  });
};

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof setupStore>;
export type AppDispatch = AppStore["dispatch"];
```

```
PostContainer.tsx : My Component
```

```js
import React from "react";
import { IPost } from "../models/IPost";
import { postAPI } from "../services/PostService";
import PostItem from "./PostItem";

const PostContainer = () => {
  const { data: posts, isLoading, error } = postAPI.useFetchAllPostsQuery(10);
  const [createPost, {}] = postAPI.useCreatePostMutation();
  const [uptadePost, {}] = postAPI.useUptadePostMutation();
  const [deletePost, {}] = postAPI.useDeletePostMutation();

  const handleCreate = async () => {
    const title = prompt();
    await createPost({ title, body: title } as IPost);
  };

  const handleRemove = (post: IPost) => {
    deletePost(post);
  };

  const handleUptade = (post: IPost) => {
    uptadePost(post);
  };

  return (
    <div className="post__list">
      <button onClick={handleCreate}>Add new Post</button>
      {isLoading && <h1>Loading</h1>}
      {error && <h1>Error</h1>}
      {posts &&
        posts.map((post) => (
          <PostItem
            remove={handleRemove}
            uptade={handleUptade}
            key={post.id}
            post={post}
          />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostContainer;
```